# Incompatible types: unexpected return value (In a method)

Tags: java

So I keep getting this error "incompatible types: unexpected return value"

```
 public static void createInsult(String name)
   {

     int sizeVerbs = getFileSize("verbs.txt"); 
      String[] verbs= new String[sizeVerbs]; 

      int sizeNouns = getFileSize("nouns.txt"); 
      String[] nouns = new String[sizeNouns]; 

      int sizeAdjectives = getFileSize("adjectives.txt"); 
      String[] adjectives = new String[sizeAdjectives]; 
      //End


      //Reading Files

      readFile(verbs, "verbs.txt");
      readFile(nouns, "nouns.txt");
      readFile(adjectives, "adjectives.txt");
      //End


      //Picking Random Word
      int adjectiveRandom = (int)(Math.random()* sizeAdjectives);
      int nounRandom = (int)(Math.random()* sizeNouns);
      int verbRandom = (int)(Math.random()* sizeVerbs);

      //End


      //Setting Random Word
      String noun = new String();
      noun = nouns[nounRandom];

      String verb = new String();
      verb = verbs[verbRandom];

      String ajective = new String();
      ajective = adjectives[adjectiveRandom];
      //End

      //Printing Insult
      return name + " " + verb + " is like a " + adjective + " " + noun;
      //End

   }
```

And this is inside my main method

```
createInsult(arena[random2].getName())
```

I believe it's somewhere where the method starts but it still doesn't work.
Also I want this code to return.
If you could explain in your answer how this works that would be great so that I don't make the same mistake!

Comment: Change the method signature to `public static String createInsult` if you want to return a String. But, seeing your comment, if you want to print however remove the return and wrap in `System.out.println(name + " " + verb + " is like a " + adjective + " " + noun);`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so very much @xxMrPHDxx